# how to unresolver import javax.jws.webservice?

Tags: java, web-services

The `import javax.jws.WebService;\` cannot be resolved in my netbeans

Can you help me?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try adding  javax.jws-3.1.2.jar to your project.